# How can I create a container component with two or more content placeholders in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have to develop a reusable component similar to this one:

[image]

It has two container parts that can hold other components unknown at the time, the main content part and the menu part:

[image]

Googling around, I have found an [example](http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/09/28/container-component-in-angular2.html) that uses the `ng-content` directive, but I don't know if it can be used more than once or not (it's the first time I use Angular for a project). This is the idea:

```
<!-- WindowComponent -->
<div class="window">
    <h4>Window title</h4>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<!-- Content -->
<div class="content">
    <app-window>
        <div>Some content</div>
    </app-window>

    <!-- How about the menu? -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use  more than once in a component.
You can break your view in to few components if needed.

- Container component
- Menu component
- Graphs/Content component

And you can put menu component and the graphs component in to container component's template.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<ng-content>` with select. Like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'transclude',
  template: `

  <header>
    <ng-content select=".header"></ng-content>
  </header>

  <main>
    <ng-content select=".main"></ng-content>
  </main>

  <footer>
   <ng-content select=".footer"></ng-content>
  </footer>

  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class TranscludeComponent  {
}
```

Usage:

```
<transclude>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="main">Main</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</transclude>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-select-class)

`<ng-content select="...">` supports selecting by:

- css classes `<ng-content select=".my-css-class">`
- ng directives `<ng-content select="[my-directive]">`
- ng component `<ng-content select="my-component">`