# Angular 4 Variable Templating

Tags: angular

Hi guys I have made an angular 4 app and I have my component : Contentholder. 
The Contentholder is just some HTML & CSS to show the content holder that I am using.

When I use the `<content-holder></content-holder>` It works fine and shows me the contentholder.

But when I use it like this:

```
<content-holder> 
    <div>
        <h2>{{ translationservice.getExpression("Kiosk.Markforgotten_Text") }}</h2>
        <p>{{ translationservice.getExpression("Kiosk.Markforgotten_Subtext") }}</p>
    </div> 
</content-holder>`
```

It Just shows me the Contentholder, Everything between the "content-holder" brackets gets left behind.

How can I use the contentholder component and also throw my own HTML from the page that I am using into it? without just copying and pasting. That is why i tried making the contentholder a component.

**----------------------UPDATE------------------------**

When I use it like this:

```
<content-holder>
<ng-content>
    <div>
        <h2>{{ translationservice.getExpression("Kiosk.Markforgotten_Text") }}</h2>
        <p>{{ translationservice.getExpression("Kiosk.Markforgotten_Subtext") }}</p>
    </div>
</ng-content>
```

I get this error:

```
    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
<ng-content> element cannot have content. ("

<content-holder>
    [ERROR ->]<ng-content>
        <div>
            <h2>{{ translationservice.getExpression("Kiosk.Markforgotten"): ng:///AppModuleShared/ForgotMarkComponent.html@3:4
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1689)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.es5.js:12801)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.es5.js:26846)
    at compiler.es5.js:26766
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.es5.js:26766)
    at compiler.es5.js:26653
    at Object.then (compiler.es5.js:1679)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26652)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26581)
```

Comment: Do you receive errors?

Comment: nope no errors! It just doesnt show the HTML that i throw between the contentholder brackets

Comment: That's perfectly normal and expected. <content-holder> will show the template of the content-holder component. Not what is between the opening and ending tag. If you want to show what is inside the tags inside the template of the component, you need to use <ng-content></ng-content> inside the template of the component.

Comment: And how does that work? I put my div between <ng-content></ng-content> but i get an error telling me that ng-content element cannot have content [my div and h2,p]

Comment: @MexLataster Can you show where you use `ng-content`?

Comment: @Lansana I updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you are trying to use `ng-content` improperly.

This is how `ng-content` works in Angular 4:

**Component:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'wrap',
    template: `
        <div class="wrap">
            <ng-content>
        </div>
    `
})
export class WrapComponent {}
```

Usage:

```
<wrap>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
<wrap>
```

**Result:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

Try implementing that usage and your problem should go away.

---

Here is an example with your component:

**Component:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'content-holder',
    template: `
        <div class="content-holder">
            <ng-content>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ContentHolderComponent {}
```

**Usage:**

```
<content-holder> 
    <div>
        <h2>{{ translationservice.getExpression("Kiosk.Markforgotten_Text") }}</h2>
        <p>{{ translationservice.getExpression("Kiosk.Markforgotten_Subtext") }}</p>
    </div> 
</content-holder>
```

**Result:**

```
<div class="content-holder"> 
    <div>
        <h2>some value</h2>
        <p>some value</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the `<ng-content>` in the component that will accept the transcluded content. Like this:

**content-holder.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'content-holder',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  styleUrls: ['./content-holder.component.css'],
})
export class ContentHolder {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  template:`
  <content-holder>
    <div> My content</div>
  </content-holder>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

Also check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49649525/5594389) for more advanced use cases of `<ng-content>` with multiple slots and live demo.

Comment: THanks alot for your help!

Comment: Please consider upvoting my answer if you found it useful :) Do the same for the accepted answer if you can.

Comment: Already did that!  But my opinion wont matter cause I have less then 15 points hahahah